# SSL Port NodeJS on Amazon Elatisc BeanStalk Single Instance

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, single-instance

Currently, there seems to be no method through BeanStalk's interface or API for allowing SSL connections on a single instance without ELB. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

## Update: Please note that AWS supports single instance SSL cert officially now: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/SSL.SingleInstance.html

Several people have voice an issue with this at Amazon's help forums, but the only method that seems to work is port forwarding.

Consider these steps:

First set your Node App to listen to a valid and open port for SSL connection. Then SSH into the instance that is running the app.

Enter: *sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to {CurrentSSLPort}*

So if you have an app running at port 8443 with HTTPS/SSL, this command would look like:
*sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to 8443*

Note that if the environment is rebuilt, you'll need to forward the port again.

Comment: how to attach the certificate with this instance?

Comment: Please note that AWS supports single instance SSL cert officially now:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/SSL.SingleInstance.html